# Should I check if route params exist inside a controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on an Express app, and one of the routes looks like this

```js
router.put(
  '/countries/:countryId/regions/:regionId/cities/:cityId',
  runAsyncWrapper(updateCity),
);
```

Inside the controller I have these checks

```js
const {
    params: { countryId, regionId, cityId },
    body,
  } = req;
   if (!countryId) throw new CountryIdRequired();
   if (!regionId) throw new RegionIdRequired();
   if (!cityId) throw new CityIdRequired();
```

Do those checks even make any sense? Since these IDs are used in the route string, is there any chance that this controller (which is used only with that one route) will be called, and some of the params will be `null` or `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express should answer with HTTP 404 if your params are not set.

Comment: I think that the status code is not correct, you should answer with 400 or 422 because the route exists, but the parameters are not set.

Comment: In a RESTful API, a resource is identified by its URI. So it's perfectly fine to send `404` if no resource can be allocated to the path. @AndresReneGutierrezT I would rather set `400` for wrong query parameters than for wrong path variables and `422` is definitely the wrong status code according to the [RFC 4918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4918#section-11.2).

Comment: OK, I'm going to check the link, thanks.